How extract and save giant tar archive in python
I have faced with the next case:
I need to extract very big tar.xc archive, which contains one .dat file with size close to 15Gb. And save file to folder.
But If I'm using tarfile.open(path/to/archive).getmembers(archive).extractall() I have MemoryError
Maybe, someone know how improve the evaluation speed in this process. Thanks
Maybe you'll need to check my code:
class RowsAccumulator:
    def __init__(self, border_list_size=300000000):
        self.border_list_size = border_list_size
        self.rows: bytes = b''
        self.generated_files = 1

    def add_row(self,row):
        # self.rows += str(row)
        self.rows += self.rows.join([row])
        return self.check_border()

    def check_border(self) -> bool:
        # if len(self.rows.encode('utf-8')) > self.border_lsit_size:
        print(len(self.rows), end='\r')
        if len(self.rows) > self.border_list_size:
            return True
        return False

    def delete_row(self):
        # self.rows = ''
        self.rows: bytes = b''
        self.generated_files += 1


def unpack_archive(path: str) -> object:
    try:
        file = tarfile.open(path, 'r:*')
    except:
        print('unexpected file type in {}'.format(path))
        return None
    print('unpacked {}'.format(path))
    return file


def deep_to_file(folder_with_archive, target_dir):
    unpacked = unpack_archive(folder_with_archive)
    if unpacked:
        for member in unpacked.getmembers():
            accum = RowsAccumulator()
            for log_row in unpacked.extractfile(member).__iter__():
                if accum.add_row(log_row):
                    with open(file_path,'w') as f:
                        f.write(accum.rows.decode(encoding='utf-8'))
                    f.close()
                    accum.delete_row()

For resolving this issue I have used iterator for ExFileObject (result of tarfile.open(path/to/archive).getmembers(archive).__iter__()), collect fixed size batches and save to files.
It's working, but very slow.
I tried to find fixed_size archive context reading (by fixed size in bytes, for example, instead row by row reading, to use reading batches with size 100m), but didn't found any methods.

Generally: An except without specified exception(s) is a bad idea.

extractfile should return an io.BufferedReader object which supports to read a fixed amount of bytes from the file.

@MichaelButscher in this case I catch exceptions, because sometimes files (potential archives) in the folder has incorrect extention)

@MichaelButscher I'm not sure, but read is not support the start point for the readable range. I mean, what I can't take from 1000 to 10005 bytes from file, for example.

I have found a solution:
used a generator with yield statement
def read_by_chunk(file_object,chunk_size):
while True:
    data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
    if not data:
        break
    yield data

